# Which word processors and websites support vertical writing of Chinese?

Tags: resources, software

I am aware of [好讀](http://www.haodoo.net), which allows you to read Chinese novels displayed vertically.

1. Is there a convenient (preferably free of charge) word processor if I wish to type a Chinese document vertically?
2. When I browse a Chinese website, it there a way to convert the writing to the vertical direction?
3. Which website(s) display Chinese vertically?

Comment: Relevant SE questions: [Vertical Chinese text with XeTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38577/vertical-chinese-text-with-xetex) (at TeX.SE) and [Plain text editor that supports vertical text (for Chinese, Japanese, etc)](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1794/plain-text-editor-that-supports-vertical-text-for-chinese-japanese-etc) (at SoftwareRecs.SE).

Answer (score 2):

[TextEdit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TextEdit)

Format/ Make layout vertical

[image]

Comment: For what it's worth, the feature is also on the context menu as Services→Orientation Layout→Vertical.  Also works on European languages, only with them, the letters also go sideways.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a convenient (preferably free of charge) word processor if I
>   wish to type a Chinese document vertically?

Microsoft word support this function. Click layout -> text direction -> vertical.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Regarding #2, you can try installing [Stylebot](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylebot/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha?hl=en) or a similar browser extension, then adding the following custom styles:

```
body * {
  writing-mode: tb-rl;
  text-orientation: upright;
}

#stylebot-container * {
    writing-mode: lr-tb !important;
}
```

Layout will be anywhere from a bit messed up to massively messed up, depending on the site, but the text will be vertical. Not sure exactly why you'd want to do this, but there you go.